# Bezout's bound and resultants - reference request

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In Terry Tao's [blog post about Bezout's inequality](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/bezouts-inequality/), he writes:

> In our notation*, this theorem states the following:
>
> **Theorem 1 (Bezout’s theorem)** Let $d=m=2$. If $V$ is finite, then it has cardinality at most $D_1 D_2$.
>
> This result can be found in any introductory algebraic geometry textbook; it can for instance be proven using the classical tool of resultants.

*Here, $V$ is the zero set of $m=2$ real polynomials in $d=2$ variables with degrees $D_1$, $D_2$.

I am looking for a reference for the proof of this version of the theorem (only an upper bound, not exact equality) with $d=m \ge 2$, preferably using resultants, that will be accessible to someone with no background in algebraic geometry. I prefer a textbook or standard reference that I can later use as a reference in a paper.

I've looked in Fulton's book *Algebraic Curves* and it is a bit too complicated for me, and it does not use resultants in the proof.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.math.us.edu.pl/~pgladki/inedita/referat.pdf).

Comment: Wouldn't this just follow from the usual Bezout's theorem? If you have two real polynomials, you can view them as complex polynomials with complex solutions, for which we know there will be exactly $D_1D_2$ solutions when viewed projectively and counting multiplicity. Real solutions would constitute a subset of these, and affine solutions would also be a subset. In other words, $D_1D_2$ is an upper bound for the number of solutions in more restrictive settings.

Comment: @SergioDaSilva, I think there is some value in not going to projective space - that the proof will be more easily readable by people who aren't familiar with projective spaces. Anyway, do you perhaps have a book reference for the proof of the usual Bezout's theorem, using resultants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is the following.

If you have two polynomials $f(x), g(x)\in A[x]$ where $A$ is a domain (including $A=k[y],$ for $k$ a field), and their respective degrees are $m$ and $n$, you wonder how to determine quickly whether they have a common factor (over the field of fractions $K$ of $A$) or not.  A quick way to realise this is that, if they had such common factor, then there would be a relation of this kind:

$$q(x)f(x)+r(x)g(x)=0,$$

where $deg\ q(x)\neq n-1, deg\ r(x)\leq m-1$ are polynomials in $A[x]$ or $K[x]$.

This is equivalent to showing that, over $K$, the following polynomials are linearly dependent:

$$f(x), xf(x), \cdots, x^{n-1}f(x), g(x), xg(x), \cdots , x^{m-1}g(x).$$

This is equivalent to saying that the determinant defining the resultant is $0$.

If $A=k[y]$, then the resultant is a polynomial in $y$ that is $0$ precisely when there is a common solution of $f(x,y_0)=0, g(x,y_0)=0$ for that particular value of $y$.

If you tilt the axes enough, you may suppose that the solutions $(x_i,y_i)$ in an algebraic closure of $k$ take different values of $y_i$, so the degree of the resultant is a precise bound for the system of equations given, namely:

$$f(x,y)=0, g(x,y)=0.$$

By using the appropriate combination, operating on the last row, one sees that the resultant is a suitable combination of polynomials

$$R(y)=a(y)f(x,y)+b(y)g(x,y).$$

Thus, indeed the degree of the resultant is an upper bound for the number of solutions of the above system, assuming $f$ and $g$ have no common factors.

(It gets tedious if I write the matrices involved, but see the link).

This link is rather self-contained and accessible.
[http://www.math.us.edu.pl/~pgladki/inedita/referat.pdf](http://www.math.us.edu.pl/%7Epgladki/inedita/referat.pdf)

LATER ADDITION (plane curves):  I do not know if you got my point.  The idea is, if you have a finite number of points in the plane, you can always choose the coordinates so that if the points are $P_i=(x_i,y_i)$, then all coordinates $y_i$ are different.  Thus you can count your points only through the resultant, so you need only count the number of zeros the resultant gives you.

INTERSECTION PRODUCT:  If you are familiar with homology theory, then you can view this as a problem of intersection in the complex projective plane, but I will omit this explanation for now.

THE CASE OF THREE VARIABLES (SKETCH):  Assume the intersection of the three hypersurfaces is finite.  This explanation is rather 'cooked-up', but let's go for it.  You have to assume, or to check, the following claim (always over the complex numbers).

**Claim:**  Let $F$ be a homogeneous polynomial in the variables $Z_0, \cdots ,Z_3$, and let $d$ be its degree.  Let $H$ be a generic plane in ${\mathbb P}$, and let $p$ be a general point (not on $F=0$ or on $H$).  Consider the projection of centre $p$ onto the plane $H$.

The projection is onto, and has degree $d$ (which is precisely the degree of intersection of a line through $p$ with the hypersurface $F=0$.)

If you have (dehomogenized) polynomials $f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z)=0$ in ${\mathbb A}^3$, you can see that (after a suitable change of variables) for general $z$ fixed the above algebraic system of equations has at most $\leq \deg f \deg g$ solutions (unless $f, g$ are very special).

The idea is that the intersection (now we view them as homogenised) $F_1=F_2=0$ is a bunch of curves $C_i$, whose total degree sums up to $d_1 d_2$ (you can reduce to the situation of plane curves, explained above, by cutting with a general plane).

Now, we intersect those curves $C_i$ with our third hypersurface ($F=F_3$) $F_3=0$, and project to $H$ from the point $p$. It's time for counting.

An argument could be written down justifying the point count, but it's tedious.  It basically says that, counting with multiplicities, if the intersection of three homogeneous polynomials $F_i$ of degrees $d_i$ is finite, then it gives rise to a cycle of intersection
$$\sum e_i P_i,$$ where $\sum e_i=d_1 d_2 d_3.$

If we consider the equation $L$ of the plane $H$, one can write a function $\varphi=F_3/L^{d_3}$, which is meromorphic, and one can study each one of the lines of the projection over each one of the curves. The idea is that the total sum of zeros - poles of the restriction of $\varphi$ is zero over each line.

It's all indeed very cooked up, but I can't think of anything nicer ATM.

PASSING TO PROJECTIVE SPACE: It is true that you don't really need it unless you want to calculate the precise intersection, and in your case you just want a bound.

REFERENCE: This graduation thesis contains the definition of resultant of $n$ polynomials in $n$ variables, though it is rather tedious.

[http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~kuenzer/diploma_deissler.pdf](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7Ekuenzer/diploma_deissler.pdf)

Comment: I don't understand how this works, for example, with 3 polynomials in 3 variables, with degrees $m, n, k$. I can look at pairs of resultants or something like that but how to get a bound $mnk$ on the number of zeros?

Comment: I tried to sketch an argument just now, but it's tedious and it is more interesting to learn the general theory, you can use Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry (2 vols., use Vol. 1).  Else one may take it as a récipé and uses it. But don't forget that the bound works when the intersection of the three equations is finite, which is generically the case but not always.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations and the effort! :)